# Appbar won't appear

Tags: python, flet

I created a program with flets and wanted to display a dark red appbar, but when I ran it only displayed a light gray page. What's wrong with my program?

```
import flet
from flet import *

myred = '#C3003D'
mydarkred = '#6C0022'
mygreen = '#05DF9D'
mywhite = '#FFFFFF'

class MedSoundApp(flet.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page:Page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page
    def build(self):
        self.page.appbar = flet.AppBar(
            toolbar_height= 100,
            bgcolor=mydarkred
        )
        return self.page.appbar
        
def main(page:flet.Page):
    page.title ='MedSound'
    page.bgcolor = myred
    page.padding = 0
    page.spacing = 0
    page.fonts = {
    "Futura Book": "/fonts/Futura Book font.ttf",
    "Futura Bold": "/fonts/Futura Bold font.ttf",
    "Futura Medium": "/fonts/futura medium bt.ttf",
    "Futura Heavy": "/fonts/Futura Heavy font.ttf",
    }   
    page.theme = flet.Theme(font_family="Futura Book")
    page.add(
        MedSoundApp(page)
        )
flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")
```

Previously I tried creating a container there, and it worked. However, when I changed it to an appbar, the UI that appeared was not as expected
[display that appears when program is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gSsz.png)

Answer (score 1):

you are using the class wrong, build is a function you have to call, it is also not necessary to add anything to the page, and you have to update the page, your code will work if you replace your main with this:

```
def main(page:flet.Page):
  page.title ='MedSound'
  page.bgcolor = myred
  page.padding = 0
  page.spacing = 0
  page.fonts = {
    "Futura Book": "/fonts/Futura Book font.ttf",
    "Futura Bold": "/fonts/Futura Bold font.ttf",
    "Futura Medium": "/fonts/futura medium bt.ttf",
    "Futura Heavy": "/fonts/Futura Heavy font.ttf",
   }   
  page.theme = flet.Theme(font_family="Futura Book")
  med = MedSoundApp(page)
  med.build()
  page.update()
```

Other way to solve the problem is not using a class, you can use a function that returns an AppBar with the content you want, and then in the main function call it like this:

```
page.appbar = function()
page.update()
```